# Unable to use basic authentication to access WCF web service

Tags: c#, wcf, kerberos, wshttpbinding, basichttpbinding

I am trying to configure a WCF service to allow for both Windows/NTLM and Basic Authentication. Unfortunately, given this configuration only Windows/NTLM works and basic authentication fails with an [http status code of 401 Unauthorized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#401).

Our IIS 7.5 server is configured to allow for both of these types of authentication.
[image]

What is wrong with the below configuration that is preventing basic authentication from working?

```
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="webBinding">
    <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" realm="XXX.YYY.com" />
    </security>
  </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

I have also tried using `basicHttpBinding`, as a forum post indicated that [`wsHttpBinding` might prevent basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877322/is-it-possible-to-get-through-a-basic-authentication-proxy-using-wshttpbinding/878720#878720) if WCF felt the password was being passed in clear text.

Comment: Have you installed an HTTP sniffer like Fiddler or Charles or even Wireshark? No? Install one and then post the results.

Answer (score 0):

I would create two end-points one that use Windows credentials and another end-point that uses Basic.

Comment: Richard I've tried using just basic and have had the same issue. No matter the configuration basic http authentication will not work.